# Animating views translation and synchronisation handling

Tags: android, animation, view, synchronization

I am trying to animate views in android. Here is the first part.

[3 views, 2 visible color and 1 translucent view that is hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Rxn.png)

Qs.) I am trying to hide the the dark blue view and move the green view to the top.

This is what I want at the end.
 [Translucent visible and green at top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO0qN.png)

The problem with translation is that how can i Get exact value to translate, also there is lots of synchronizing problem. How can I sync all these animation.

I mean to say **hide the dark blue** view **while moving up the green one** and **appearing the translucent one**. Vice versa too.

Comment: just use `AnimatorSet` to play your animators together

Comment: I have used that but the translation is problem too. How can I move the view exactly at the top and then exactly at bottom, without cutting the view ( which is happening now).

Comment: use `"tranlationX"` / `"translationY"` properties

Comment: Can you write a more elaborate ans.? I have used that property but I am asking for the value to be put.